# React Hook Form and Zod - Conditional Validation for Time Inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I'm working on a React application using React Hook Form and zod for form validation. I have a form with checkboxes for each day of the week, and when a checkbox is selected, it enables two input fields for start time and end time. I'm struggling to implement conditional validation for these time inputs.

Here are the requirements:

Both start and end times are required.
Start time cannot be equal to or greater than the end time.
The challenge is that initially, all checkboxes (and corresponding inputs) are disabled, and errors should appear only after both input fields are filled, not immediately after enabling the checkbox.

I'm wondering how to achieve this conditional validation in React Hook Form and zod. Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the schemas:

```
const hoursSchema = z
  .object({
    day: z.string(),
    checked: z.boolean(),
    from: z.tuple([z.number(), z.number()]).nullish(),
    to: z.tuple([z.number(), z.number()]).nullish(),
  })
```

```
export const availableHoursSchema = z.object({
  availability: z.array(hoursSchema),
});
```

Then I added superRefine to hoursSchema:

```
 hoursSchema.superRefine(({ from, to, checked }, ctx) => {
    if (!checked) return;

    if (!from && !to) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "Provide both start and end times.",
      });

      return;
    }

    if (!from) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "Provide start time.",
      });

      return;
    }

    if (!to) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "Provide end time.",
      });

      return;
    }

    if (from[0] > to[0] || (from[0] === to[0] && from[1] > to[1])) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "End time cannot be earlier than start time",
      });

      return;
    }

    if (from[0] === to[0] && from[1] === to[1]) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "Starting and ending hours can't be the same!",
      });

      return;
    }
  });
```

The very simplified version of the form itself looks like this:

```
<form>
  <Controller
    render={() => {
      <>
        <Checkbox />
        <TimeStart />
        <TimeEnd />
      </> 
    }}
 />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried using `.superRefine()`, but then, the form is validated right after enabling the checkbox

Comment: Can you post the code you’ve worked on?

Comment: Yes, of course 